# Resizing HTML div object and child elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

A warning first off that I am pretty much a fish out of water with HTML, CSS and JS so no level of detail would be too great in any responses. I've found some similar questions addressing CSS transforms but with my limited knowledge I can't tell if they are the route I should be going down....

So I have a HTML  object within a view of my MVC app. It is formed like below and forms a business card like element for each item in a list (a list of people objects, basically), showing name, company, notes, image etc. of the people in the list.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid lightgray;resize: both; overflow: hidden;height:240px;margin-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;width:320px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:220px;">
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            @if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }
        </div>
        @if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b>@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1) days<br /></div>
        }
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b>@itm.DateJoined.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company<br /></div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        @if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { 
            <div style="padding-top:5px;"><b>Notes</b></div>
            <div style="width: 220px;">@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(itm.Notes))</div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="profileImage" style="height:100%;float:left;margin-left:5px;padding-top:5px;padding-right:5px;text-align:right;">
    @if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" />
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

As the list populates/changes these business card elements fill the page forming a grid (the grid is not pre programmed, the elements actually just form one long row technically which starts a new row when the previous one is filled).

I'd like these elements to be variable in size so that the user can alter the size of them depending on their screen resolution or their particular purpose.

How can I dynamically resize not only the div object itself, but all of it's child elements including the `img` object. I'd like this to be user controlled eventually via a slider or drop down box consisting of preset options like 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc....

Can it be done? Or are there easy alternatives to how I'm doing this?

JK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed most of the server side logic by enclosing it in html comments, just remove to restore your custom logic.  Is this something like what you wanted?

Here is it in multiples (dropdown):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#dim').change(function(){
    var cl='by'+$('#dim option:selected').text();
    $('#deck').removeClass().addClass(cl);
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height:240px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.card .profileImage {
  float:right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
}
.card > div > div:last-child { margin-top: 10px; }
.card > div > div:last-child b {display:block;}
ul { font-size: 0; margin:0; padding:0; }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; }
.by2 .card { width: 50%; }
.by3 .card { width: 33%; }
.by4 .card { width: 25%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dim'>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<ul id="deck" class='by2'>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>
</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
</ul>
```

And a slider:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#slider').slider({
    value: 9,
    min: 1,
    max: 10
  });
  $('#slider').on('slide',function(event,ui){
      var w=100/(11-ui.value);
      var f=(1-((100-w)/100*(100-w)/100))*30;
      $('.card').css('width',w+'%').css('font-size',f+'px');
    });
  
});
```

```css
/* Base styles */
ul { font-size: 0; margin:0; padding:0; }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; }

/* Card style */
.card {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height:240px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 22.5px;
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.card .profileImage {
  float:right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
}
.card > div > div {
  word-break: break-all;
}
/* Card notes styles */
.card > div > div:last-child { margin-top: 10px; }
.card > div > div:last-child b {display:block;}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<ul id="deck">
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>
</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
<li class="card">
    <!--@if (itm.ImageUrl != null)
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/@itm.ImageUrl" class="profileImage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Content/images/No_Photo_Silo.jpg" class="profileImage" />
    }-->
    <img class="profileImage" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div>
        <div><h4>@itm.FirstName @itm.LastName</h4></div>
        <div>
            <b>Last Visit: </b>
            <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                @itm.LastVisit.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw("n/a")
            }-->
        </div>
        <!--@if (itm.LastVisit != DateTime.MinValue)
        {-->
            <div><b>Time Elapsed: </b><!--@(itm.TimeSinceLastVisit + 1)--> days</div>
        <!--}-->
        <div><b>Date Joined: </b><!--@itm.DateJoined.ToString("-->dd MMM yyyy<!--")--></div>
        <div><b>Company: </b>@itm.Company</div>
        <div><b>Position: </b>@itm.Position</div>

        <!--@if (itm.Notes != null) 
        { -->
            <div><b>Notes</b><!--@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(-->itm.Notes<!--))--></div>
        <!--}-->
    </div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm a little confused by your answer. From what I gather you've simplified the whole thing considerably and created two css classes. I don't understand what the `.card > div {

}` is doing, and I'm unsure how this would enable me to dynamically resize the parent div element and it's child div element...?

Comment: Sorry, that class did nothing.  I was going to use it then realized there was nothing I needed to put in there.  I've updated the answer with an example of multiple cards.

Comment: Added slider example with transitions.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll try switch to this today and upvote if successful

Comment: Answer accepted. I wondered if you knew how I could also resize the text based on the same slider....?

Comment: Updated slider example with resizing fonts.  You can pick whatever scaling  you want.  I just picked one that looked fairly reasonable.